# Elasticsearch _cat/indices is giving error?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce

Currently I am using elasticsearch helper scan api, but it is not able to fetch data.

command :

```
helpers.scan(
        client=client,
        query={"query":{"match_all":{}}},
        scroll='10m',
        index="debug", 
        doc_type = "tool", 
        _source=True
    )
```

output :

```
......
generator object scan at 0x1556640
generator object scan at 0x1556640
generator object scan at 0x1556640
generator object scan at 0x1556640
generator object scan at 0x1556640
.......
```

when I am doing

```
curl -XGET"http://localhost:9200/debug/tool/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*"
```

(only 10 by default)
it is able to fetch the data.

After digging the elastic when I check the indices using this command :

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices
```

I found this : `No handler found for uri [/_cat/indices] and method [GET]`

But when I am using `http://localhost:9200/_aliases`, I can see my indexing. Why indexes is not coming when I run `_cat/indices` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_cat/indices` is available in ES versions after 1.0.x.

Comment: How does this help?